# How is labor demand measured?

Tags: macroeconomics, labor-economics, wages, technology, national-accounts

For instance, in the introduction of this [paper](https://economics.mit.edu/files/16338) (first paragraph), talking about Figure 1, they say that labor demand is measured as the real wage bill normalized by population.

Is it common to measure it with the wage bill? But isn't the wage bill an equilibrium result of the interaction between demand and supply?